# FizzBuzz type game with user inputs - integer error

Tags: python, input, integer

I am learning python and have made a simple FizzBuzz game with user inputs. I have tried converting the inputs to integers as seen below but I am getting the error :

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Can someone let me know where I am going wrong?

```
x = print(int(input('enter a starting value:' )))
y = print(int(input('enter a final value:' )))


def fizzbuzz(x,y):
    for number in range(x, y):
        if (number % 3) == 0 and (number % 5) == 0:
            print('fizzbuzz')
        elif (number % 3) == 0:
            print('fizz')
        elif (number % 5) == 0:
            print('buzz')
        else:
            print(number)


print(fizzbuzz(x,y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `print` from first 2 statements. it should be:

```
x = int(input('enter a starting value:' ))
y = int(input('enter a final value:' ))
```

**Note:** `print` is for printing the output on console. Never use `print` while assigning a value to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the print() function around the int()

```
x = print(int(input('enter a starting value:' )))
y = print(int(input('enter a final value:' )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```py
x = print(int(input('enter a starting value:' )))
y = print(int(input('enter a final value:' )))
```

with

```py
x = int(input('enter a starting value:' ))#No need to use print() here
y = int(input('enter a final value:' ))#same for this statement
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp) is what print actually does
And this is how [input](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp#:%7E:text=Python%20input%20%28%29%20Function%201%20Definition%20and%20Usage.,default%20message%20before%20the%20input.%204%20More%20Examples) works

Then your code should look something like this:

```py
x = int(input('enter a starting value:' ))
y = int(input('enter a final value:' ))


def fizzbuzz(x,y):
    for number in range(x, y):
        if (number % 3) == 0 and (number % 5) == 0:
            print('fizzbuzz')
        elif (number % 3) == 0:
            print('fizz')
        elif (number % 5) == 0:
            print('buzz')
        else:
            print(number)


print(fizzbuzz(x,y))
```